# Input tag onChange returning undefine value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rsuite

I have been stuck on one issue to fetch the input text field from the input field. Essentially, I want to make a search function that gets the text and processes it further.
Please refer to the code for the information and returning div is at the bottom.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { Input, InputGroup, Icon} from 'rsuite';
import { Button, IconButton, ButtonGroup, ButtonToolbar } from 'rsuite';
import './App.css';
import Search from './search.js';

// import default style
import 'rsuite/dist/styles/rsuite-default.css';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const styles = {
  marginBottom: 10
};
const center = {
  padding: '25% 25% 25%' 
}
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: 'Nothing'
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event){;

    this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value});
  };

  render(){
        return (
          <div >
            <div style={center} >
                <InputGroup style={styles}> <Input size="md" value={this.inputValue} onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e)} /><InputGroup.Addon>
                <Button appearance="default"><Icon icon="search" /></Button>
                </InputGroup.Addon>
              </InputGroup>
            
            </div>
            
          </div>
        )
      }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a `;` in the start of your `handleInputChange` function.

`Input` from `rsuite` directly returns value onChange but you are referring to `e.target.value`.

And also the value should be `this.state.inputValue`

Here is the solution.

```
handleInputChange(value) {
    console.log("values>>>>", value);
    this.setState({ inputValue: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={center}>
          <InputGroup style={styles}>
            {" "}
            <Input
              size="md"
              value={this.state.inputValue}
              onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e)}
            />
            <InputGroup.Addon>
              <Button appearance="default">
                <Icon icon="search" />
              </Button>
            </InputGroup.Addon>
          </InputGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

you can also refer to https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-field-njxn0?file=/src/App.js:590-1213

Comment: You are a legend, man! Thank you very much

Comment: ...thanks for the response...always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple. You are setting `value={this.inputValue}` but you should use `value={this.state.inputValue}`. Because `this.inputValue` doesn't exist, your value gets set to undefined. Using `value={this.state.inputValue}` should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I am still getting the same issue

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
App.handleInputChange
  29 | 
  30 | handleInputChange(event){;
  31 | 
> 32 |   this.setState({inputValue: event.target.value});
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | 
  35 | render(){
View compiled
▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.```

Comment: There is a `;` in your handleInputChange right after the `{`